# How should I change currentIndex property of BottomNavigationBar on Navigating to another screen?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a bottom navigation bar widget for my Flutter app. On tapping specific item it is navigating to another screen. However, I don't know how to update current index in this case so that selected tab gets highlighted. Here is my code:

```
        BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFF7B19),
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                size: lh / 25,
              ),
              label: 'Events',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.people_alt_outlined,
                size: lh / 25,
              ),
              label: 'Councils',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: 0,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.grey[900],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[50],
          onTap: (int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllEventsScreen()));
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Councils()));
            }
          })
```

[image: Here is the output]

I have tried creating a variable `_selectedIndex` for this which I was updating inside the function I have provided for onTap as shown:

```
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.grey[900],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[50],
          onTap: (int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllEventsScreen()));
              _selectedIndex = 0;
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Councils()));
              _selectedIndex = 1;
            }
```

But this doesn't seems to work. I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `_selectedIndex` with a PageView and set the onTap like this :

```
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.grey[900],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[50],
          onTap: (int index) {
              setState(()=>_selectedIndex=index);
            }
```

Reading this [article](https://karthikponnam.medium.com/flutter-pageview-withbottomnavigationbar-fb4c87580f6a) would be helpful

**Edit: This is a full example**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  late PageController _pageController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: _selectedIndex,
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
              _pageController.animateToPage(index,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: "Home",
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: "Search",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test App'),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Home"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Search"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: adding setState() method doesn't seems to work properly. It may be changing the current index but that becomes visible after navigating again to the original screen and not changing when it is clicked.

Comment: If you want to save the state of the selected index use Provider or Bloc for state management

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the first answer or you could go with `TabBarView`

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        Container(),
        Container()
      ]
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
      tabs: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllEventsScreen()));
            },
            child: Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                size: lh / 25,
              ),
              text: 'Events',
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Councils()));
            },
            child: Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.people_alt_outlined,
                size: lh / 25,
              ),
              text: 'Councils',
            ),
          )]
    )
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's been 1 year, but i ran with the same situation, i've been trying to solve it , the main points are:

1. Create the bottom bar with screens
2. update the index accordingly
3. save the state of the index

Basic bottom Nav bar with design

````
```
  final PageController _controller = PageController();
  final int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _screens = const [
    Home(),
    Screen2(),
    Screen3()
  ];
  
  void onTap(int index) {
    _controller.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
       selectedItemColor: Colors.yellow,
       unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
       showUnselectedLabels: true,
       showSelectedLabels: true,
       elevation: 3,
       currentIndex: _currentIndex,
       onTap: (index) {
        _controller.jumpToPage(index);
        setState(() {
         _currentIndex = index;
        });
       },
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Home"),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "screen2"),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "screen3"),
       ],
      ),
    body: PageView(
     physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     controller: _controller,
     children: _screens,
   ),
);}
````

For saving the state of the current index, i wrapped a Stack with the PageView!

```
  Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _controller,
            children: _screens,
          ),
        ],
      )
```

This is the trick, i hope it will work with you as well!